# ASP .NET MVC - Utilizar um @Html.DropDownList para duas ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, input, controller, dropdownlist

Olá,

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com **ASP .NET MVC** e utilizando a API EPPlus para exportação XLS.

Na View de um relatório de equipamentos possuo dois **@Html.DropDownList** com *Tipo de Equipamento* e *Status* Respectivamente.

Para a exibição do relatório estou trabalhando com um `Input` do tipo `Submit` chamado **Filtrar**, que envia o **Id** tanto do *Tipo* quanto do *Status* para a consulta na base de dados através da `ActionResult` da própria view.

Como eu poderia utilizar estes mesmos dois `DropDownList` para enviar, a partir de um `Input` **Exportar**, os parâmetros para uma outra `Action` do meu `controller` que fará a mesma busca e retornará um XLSX?

Segue o trecho do código cshtml:

```
<div class="ibox-content">
<div class="row">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <div class="col-sm-5 m-b-xs">
            @Html.DropDownList("TipoEquipamento", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "input-sm form-control input-s-sm inline" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5 m-b-xs">
            @Html.DropDownList("StatusEquipamento", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "input-sm form-control input-s-sm inline" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Filtrar" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }

    @using (Html.BeginForm("ExportarDados", "Signv", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Exportar" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Segue estrutura das Actions do meu controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(int TipoEquipamento, int StatusEquipamento)
    {
       .... Código da Action...
    }

    public ActionResult ExportarDados(int TipoEquipamento, int StatusEquipamento)
    {
        .... Código da Action...
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tive que fazer algo parecido certa vez, chamar duas `actions` diferentes passando a mesma coisa, no meu caso era um model, fiz isso:

Coloquei tudo dentro do mesmo `BeginForm`, um **submit button** aponta para a `action` declarada dentro do `BeginFiorm` como você já fez, e o outro **submit button** como abaixo:

```
<input  type="submit" formaction="@Url.Action("OutraAction", "MesmoController")">
```

acredito que vai dar certo pelo que você falou a primeira `Action` já está funcionando direitinho.

Acho que pode ficar algo assim:

```
<div class="ibox-content">
<div class="row">
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Signv", FormMethod.Get))
{
        <div class="col-sm-5 m-b-xs">
        @Html.DropDownList("TipoEquipamento", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "input-sm form-control input-s-sm inline" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 m-b-xs">
        @Html.DropDownList("StatusEquipamento", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "input-sm form-control input-s-sm inline" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Filtrar" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Exportar" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input  type="submit" formaction="@Url.Action("ExportarDados", "Signv")">
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Deu boa! Obrigado pela ajuda!!